# In Cocoa, when is view controller instantiated?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am building a Cocoa application on Mac OS X 10.7 using Xcode 4.2. Within it, my UI has a controller, ViewController, in which I want to instantiate an instance of the model class, e.g. Model which performs the main logic. So far, I have written:

```
@implementation ViewController // originally wrote Model, should be ViewController, apologies! My mistake/original post!
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        model = [[Model alloc] init];
    }
return self;
}
@end
```

Would this code work? I have also seen examples using the `-(void)awakeFromNib:` method, although I am not entirely sure what this method does. Would that be the better location to instantiate the model object?

**EDIT: Sorry! The implementation above should read `@implementation ViewController`! Many thanks to those who pointed out this mistake! Would this code work or should I use `awakeFromNib`?**

Comment: This is a nice one. You can watch your system becoming more and more unresponsive until your application is using up all the RAM available!

Comment: Oops! The implementation should read @implementation ViewController!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like it will recurse infinitely as it allocates and inits an infinite chain of model objects (because `-[Model init]` is calling `-[Model init]`).

Comment: Oops! The implementation should read @implementation ViewController!

Comment: Ah. In that case, you should consider timing, as you implied in your initial subject. -awakeFromNib seems like a decent time to do things, since you can be sure that outlets have been hooked up and such. -init, or -initWithFrame:/-initWithCoder: (depending on exact circumstances) have a few differences. They'll be called before IBOutlets are hooked up, and if the same object is present in more than one nib (for example if it loads a nib and sets itself as file's owner), it will be init'd once, but awakened more than once.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are assigning [super init], aka object of super class to self (subclass). Later, it may cause you problems like undefined selectors. That will happen, when you will assign/read you object (subclass) properties or call methods not present in superclass.